# javascript print issue with the iframe

Tags: javascript, html

We have a html page having some html content & also one iframe. I need to add a print functionality to print the whole page with the iframe content also.
I have tried window.print() function, but it leaves the iframe contents. 
Can anybody suggest me way to print it using javascript?

Cheers!!

Comment: *"but it leaves the iframe contents"* Not sure what that means.

Comment: @epascarello i suspect he means hit leaves out the contents on the printed material; probably a block with a bunch of whitespace

Comment: This question hovers between being too broad, or off topic. Please be more specific. In order to get every browser printing the whole page & the iframe -- in a similar manner to `window.print()` -- you'd likely have to configure each browser's print options. This could possibly be done on a personal basis, but would not work for the general public (& would mean this question isn't about programming). If you require this for the general public you may be able to use a jslib (like [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)), but it's more than likely these will also skip iframe contents.